# InternalError: Blas GEMV launch failed: m=4, n=800 [[{{node PartitionedCall/MatMul}}]] [Op:__inference_train_97]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, memcpy, tensorflow2.0

[image: **enter image description here**]

Error name

> Blas GEMV launch failed:  m=4, n=800 [Op:MatMul] name: MatMul/

Just installed

- tensorflow 2.0.0
- Cuda 10.1
- Cudnn 7.6.4

code :

```py
for i in range(100):    
     W, b = train(X_train, Y_train, W, b)
     print('Current Training Loss on iteration', i, ' -- ', loss(Y_train, 
  prediction(X_train, W, b)).numpy())`enter code here`
```

I am unable to solve the above internal error

In anaconda prompt, I am getting 
F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_util.cc:342] CPU->GPU Memcpy failed

Comment: Please post your error as text and also the script/function that you're getting the error in.

Comment: error is cleared, it was there due to Cuda file, the filename is name cudart64_100.dll

Comment: I need to restart my kernel always to fix this bug even after fixing the file

Comment: I got lucky by downgrading to: 
CUDA 10.0
cuDNN 7.6.2

try these versions if you have already manually placed cudart64_100.dll in your folder